# Onenote API PHP - trying to post multiple PHP files, submit.php return blank page

Tags: php, onenote

I’m having some issues with modifying the sample PHP code from the Outlook API PHP code to iterate through a series of PHP files to post.  I have the Client ID, Secret, and callback URL in the file correctly.

I’ve modified the code as follows:

submit.php:

```
    function createPageWithFile($pdffile)
    {

        $ch = $this->initCurl();

        //ISO 8601 standard time stamp
        $date = date('c');

        //Read the file into memory
        //Note that reading entire large files into memory could create problems if
        //  PHP doesn't have enough memory to work with
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($pdffile);

        //Includes the Presentation part and embedded file data part
        //Each has its own Content-Disposition and Content-Type headers
        //The request must end with a blank line to be a valid Multipart request
        $postdata = <<<POSTDATA
--{$this->boundary}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A page created with a file attachment (PHP Sample)</title>
    <meta name="created" value="$date"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>This is a page with a PDF file attachment</h1>
    <object
        data-attachment="$pdffile"
        data="name:embeddedFile"
        type="application/pdf" />
    <img data-render-src="name:embeddedFile" alt="$pdffile" width="1500" />
  </body>
</html>
--{$this->boundary}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="embeddedFile"
Content-Type: application/pdf

$fileContents
--{$this->boundary}--

POSTDATA;

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->finish($ch,$response,$pdffile);
    }
```

Later in the same file:

```
        case "file":
            $pdffiles = glob('*.{pdf,PDF}', GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach($pdfiles as $pdffile) {
                $OneNoteRequest->createPageWithFile($pdffile);
              }
            break;
```

Ideas?

Comment: what problems do you exactly have with it? what errors do you get?

Comment: What error/issue are you running into?